# UIImage rotating around its own axis? Possible?

Tags: swift, animation, uiimageview, uiimage

I need a `UIImageView` initialized with an image that rotates around its own axis in the same way it does in this
[GIF example](http://rs1126.pbsrc.com/albums/l609/ahipol/quarter-2-textures1.gif~c200).

My task is actually a little more complicated because I also need to turn a flat image into a thick, coin-like 3D image, but I won't bother anyone here with that. The only thing I want to know right now is whether it's possible to animate a `UIImage` like the example above, and if so, then how do I do it?

Comment: Have a look at this link http://radar.oreilly.com/2013/07/rotating-a-uiview-in-3d.html

Comment: @Malik Thanks, I'll try this out!